# How to stop a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems that `getresult()` is trying to `console.log('here', x)`  before `getMathvalue()` finish is task.
I would like to "pause" `getresult()` so it would only `console.log('here', x)` when `getMathvalue()` is done

Here I'm trying to get a specific value a only this value which is `value` after `getMathvalue()` finished is task

```js
function quickmath() {

  const [value, setvalue] = useState()

  function getMathvalue() {
    var a = 1
    a++
    setvalue(a)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMathvalue()
  }, [])

  getresult({ value })

  function getresult(x) {
    console.log('here', x)
  }
```

[Obtained Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8snS.png)

[Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ktrY.png)

**Edit ---**

I added and ,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getresult({ value })
  }, [value]);
```

there is still  value as
[undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7WNj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few cases for this situation, if you are talking about output from first render, then this code works fine, because useEffect will call it's function only after first render will finish, so your getresult() will be called earlier then getMathValue().

Its hard to understand what real life situation you are trying to solve here because code is abstract.

For example if you want to make something after your value will be updated, you can create a second useEffect with `value` in dependency array. That way you will get your `getresult` function called after your getMathValue will finish its work.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getresult({value}) // will be called after value was updated
}, [value])
```

If this explanation\solution doesn't help you, pls, provide more case specific details to better understand situation.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I'm trying to get a value in `getresult( )` that's not undifined because my component wont  be able to render a undifined value

Comment: Is there a way to have a output from first render equal to `value = 2`

Comment: In case if you need that calculation for render, you can move your functions to render, for example `<SomeComponent value={getResult({value})} />`, or modify your function that make all calculations and instead of putting value into state, use it directly. And one more option, you can just put `if (value === undefined) return null`, and that way you will just skip first render. Your component will be mounted with no DOM at all and after first render it will make calculations and render your component

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the function call in useEffect, then everything will work correctly:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getresult({ value })
  }, [value]);
  

  function getresult(x) {
    console.log('here', x)
  }
```

The functional components of react work like normal functions. Any change in the state of the component causes the entire code inside the function (component) to be called.

To respond to changes in the values in the state, use useState with the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that on the first render, you are calling the `getresult` function and also triggering the `useEffect` call. That is why the *value* starts as `undefined`.

If you want to get the specific *value* as soon you change the *state* you can wrap your method in other `useEffect` call:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // using an if clause because *value* starts as undefined on the first call
  if (value) {
    getresult({ value }); // this method would be called each time the *value* changes
  }
}, [value]);
```

With this, you would be able to avoid calling the `getresult` method on each render (don't forget to remove it from your main component).